# jQgrid In-Line Edit:-How to give specific edittype to particular jqgrid cell?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using In-Line Edit:I want to give different edit type to each cell in the same column rather than giving only one edittype to whole column.1st row's 2nd column should have edit type as select,2nd row's 2nd column should have edit type as textarea etc..

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to modify the jqGrid source code.  It's open source, so get crackin' :)